# How to remove an element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to remove the existing html when the selectbox val == 0. Here is my HTML,

```
<div class="info-cont">
    <ul class="map-list">
        <li>
            <span class="left">
                <label>Name 1</label>
            </span>
            <span class="right">
                <select class="combo">
                    <option selected="selected" value="0"></option>
                    <option value="1">F name</option>
                    <option value="2">M name</option>
                    <option value="3">L name</option>
                </select>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Note : There are about 10 selectboxes in my page like the above,

and jquery for the above is,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#save').click(function () {
        var comboLength = $('.combo').length;
        var selectedLength = $('.combo option:selected[value!=0]').length;
        if (comboLength == selectedLength) {
            alert('Thanks all the fields are selected');
            return false;
        }
        if ($('.combo option:selected[value==0]')) {
            $("div.info-cont ul.map-list li span.right").append("<br>Please select an appropriate value").addClass('validerror');
        } else {
            $("div.info-cont ul.map-list li span.right").html("");
            $("div.info-cont ul.map-list li span.right").removeClass('validerror');
        }
        return false;
    })
});
```

What i need to do in the else condition?(My else part is not funct). Also when i click the submit button for the second time, I should not append a html to which i already received in my first click. Any help? Thanks...

Comment: `if($('.combo option:selected[value==0]'))` will always be `true`, since objects always evaluate to `true`.

Comment: `if($('.combo option:selected[value==0]'))` will always be true. instead you could put `if($('.combo option:selected[value==0]').length > 0)` its true when your selector returns an element/elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `if` to

```
if($('.combo option:selected').val() === '0'){
```

---

All issues can be resolved with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#save').click(function(){
        var combo = $('.combo'), // get all combo elements
            selected = $('.combo').filter(function(){
                return $(this).find('option[value!="0"]:selected').length;
            }), // get all valid combo elements
           unselected = combo.not(selected); // get all non-valid combo elements

        // clear previous error messages
        combo
            .closest('.right') // find containing .right element
            .removeClass('validerror') // remove error class
            .find('.errormessage') // find error message
            .remove(); // remove error message

        // chech if all combos are valid
        if (combo.length === selected.length) {
            alert('Thanks all the fields are selected');
            return false;
        }

        // highlight non-valid elements
        unselected
            .closest('.right')
            .addClass('validerror')
            .append('<div class="errormessage">Please select an appropriate value</div>');

        return false;
    });
});
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Y3RrH/

Comment: my form contains some 10 select boxes with a same class called combo. So i need to check each select boxes val() and append a html text below the particular select box for which the val() == 0. My default value for all the select boxes are 0.

Comment: can you post the HTML because the part you assign the `validerror` does not show how the `.right` element relates to the `select` element.

Comment: Here it is, 

<div class="info-cont">
   <ul class="map-list">
    <li><span class="left"><label>Name 1</label></span> <span class="right">
     <select class="combo">
                      <option selected="selected" value="0"></option>
       <option value="1">F name</option>                   
       <option value="2">M name</option>
       <option value="3">L name</option> 
     </select>
                    </span>
    </li>
                </ul></div>

Comment: @Riyas: Code is hard to read in comments. Please edit your question instead.